# setState not working in componentDidMount() - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have been having a few problems with using the setState function in componentDidMount().

What I am trying to do: I am trying to make an HTML5 circle responsive (Go bigger if browser window is bigger and vice versa).

What I have done so far: I have been storing the dimensions in state called containerDim. By Default this is set to null. Here is a very basic implementation of what I've done:

```
class App extends React.Component  {
  constructor(props)  {
    super(props);
    this.state = {containerDim: null};
    this.resizeCircle = this.resizeCircle.bind(this)  //To not loose value of this
  }

  componentDidMount()  {

    var dimensions = window.getComputedStyle(this.refs.responsiveContainer); //Used to get width and height

    this.setState({
      containerDim: {width:dimensions.width, height: dimensions.height}
    });

   window.addEventListener("resize", this.resizeCircle));

  }

 resizeCircle()  {  //THE RESIZING WORKS, THE initial setting of state doesn't
   var dimensions = window.getComputedStyle(this.refs.responsiveContainer); //Used to get width and height

    this.setState({
      containerDim: {width:dimensions.width, height: dimensions.height}
    });

 }



  render()  {
    return (
     <div ref={"responsiveContainer"} >
       <Circle dimensions={this.state.containerDim} />
     </div>
    );
  }
} 

//Circle component

class Circle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props)  {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps()  {

    console.log(this.props.dimensions); //THIS LOGS OUT NULL

  }

  render()  {
    CIRCLE GOES HERE
  }

}
```

Basically what I am trying to do with this code is to get the width and height of "responseContainer" and pass it as a prop to the `<Circle />` component.

The above does not work as the setState does not change the state whatsoever.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

This "Works" but I feel that it is not correct and there should be a better way:

```
 var dimensions = window.getComputedStyle(this.refs.container);

  setTimeout(function()  {


  this.setState({
    screenDim:{width:dimensions.width, height:dimensions.height}
  });
}.bind(this),0);

this.setState({
  screenDim:{width:dimensions.width, height:dimensions.height}
});
```

Comment: Have you got any errors?

Comment: The problem is that when I call setState nothing is actually changing.. the containerDim will still be null. The problem is that setState will only do something if I call it twice. The even weirder thing is that even though setState doesn't change anything, it still calls componentWillReceiveProps..

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but why not just use CSS (fluid width) to resize the circle?

Comment: Can you do this for HTML canvas circles? If so I might have a look at that but I think this would be a good learning experience for me anyways

Comment: Oh you were using canvas for drawing, never mind then :)

Answer (score 1):

The component does not listen to state modifications in didMount; that means that even if the state is updated the repaint is not triggered.

Comment: So where would you recommend me using  setState where I can tell my Circle component what the height and width are of the responsiveContainer?

Comment: @pinturic are you able to provide a reference link? From the [docs on the component lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) with regards to`componentDidMount()` it says "Setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering."

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
componentDidMount()  {
    setInterval((function() {
      var dimensions = window.getComputedStyle(this.refs.responsiveContainer); //Used to get width and height

      this.setState({
        containerDim: {width:dimensions.width, height: dimensions.height}
      });
    }).bind(this), 1000);
  }
```

Comment: I tried it and in the componentWillReceiveProps() I am recieving a signal that their was a prop change but when it prints out it is still null... After the first Interval it works though

Comment: EDIT: I have added the resizing functionality to the example, the only thing I am having trouble with is sending the initial width and height of the responsiveContainer to the Circle Component

Comment: EDIT2: Hmmm thats really weird... I set the setInterval amount to 10 secs and even then the first time didn't work and but all other intervals do work..

Comment: Change `componentDidMount ` to `componentWillMount` and remove the setInterval stuff.

Comment: The problem with that is that I need to access my ref so if I change componentDidMount to componentWillMount it can't access my parent container